# joomla template error

Tags: templates, joomla1.6, joomla-template

I installed a joomla template but the following error comes up every time:

---

> Notice: Undefined variable: my in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla16\templates\cartion\index.php on line 36
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla16\templates\cartion\index.php on line 36

---

---

> FATAL ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION GETCFG() ON A NON-OBJECT IN
>   C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\JOOMLA16\TEMPLATES\CARTION\SUCKERFISH.PHP ON LINE 763

---

How should I go about resolving this?

I am sharing the code as well:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php if($my->id) initEditor(); ?> #lin36

 if ($mainframe->getCfg('shownoauth')) {



  $sql = ("SELECT m.*, count(p.parent) as cnt" .



"\nFROM #__menu AS m" .#763
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//global $mainframe was deprecated in Joomla 1.5 and completely removed from Joomla 1.6. 
//global $mainframe;
$app =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
//$access   = !$mainframe->getCfg( 'shownoauth' );
$access = $app->getCfg( 'shownoauth' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it's because `$mainframe` is not defined,

`$mainframe = new some_classname();` ?

also looks like this template missing the required classes which defines `$mainframe`